# git pull no tracking info for my branch after merging a branch from another remote to my branch

Tags: git, github, git-pull

There is a repository called `main_repo`, that me and my colleague `forked`. So, my colleague created a branch called `new_changes` on her fork and branched out from my branch called `my_branch` and made new changes. Yesterday I merged her pull request of her branch to my branch on stash using the merge button.

On her pull request page it says `MERGED her_fork_repo new_changes` to `my_branch` in commit `1234`.Supposedly if I `git pull` on my branch on intellij I would see my colleague's new changes, but instead it says:

> ```
> There is no tracking information for the current branch.
> Please specify which branch you want to rebase against.
> See git-pull(1) for details.
>
>     git pull <remote> <branch>
>
> If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:
>
>     git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> my_branch
> ```

From my branch when I typed `git remote` it shows `origin`.I have also tried `git pull origin my_branch` but git says `Already up to date`.

And from `my_branch` 's pull request page (to merge into `main_repo`), I didn't see the new changes also, what should I do so that the new changes is reflected on my branch?

Comment: When you say "me and my colleague forked", do you mean it's a single fork or 2 respective forks for yourself and your colleague? And by "I merged her pull request of her branch to my branch", do you mean the pull request was merged on her fork itself?

Comment: Can you share what you see when you run `git remote -v`?

Comment: "me and my colleague forked" means 2 respective forks for myself and my colleague
"I merged her pull request of her branch to my branch" means the PR was merged to my fork, but instead that was my mistake, it was actually merged to the main_repo
When I run git remote -v I see 
origin https://link-to-my-fork-repo (fetch)
origin https://link-to-my-fork-repo (push)
Anyway the problem is solved now thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On her pull request page it says MERGED her_fork_repo new_changes to my_branch in commit 1234

A PR can be between two branches of the same repository, or between branches of a fork repo and the upstream original repository that was forked.

If your colleague PR was merged, make sure it *where*: it it is on the original upstream repository, you would need to add that upstream remote URL to your own local clone in order to be able to fetch "commit 1234".

```
 cd /path/to/local/clone/of/my/fork
 git remote add upstream https://url/upstream/original/repository
 git fetch upstream
 git merge upstream/my_branch
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @VonC
It made me realised I merged my colleague's PR which was pointed to `main_repo` instead of my fork repo. So now on the `main_repo` and my fork repo, there is a branch of the same name which is `my_branch`. What I did was I

```
git remote add main https://git-link-for-main-repo
git pull main my_branch
```

And then fixed any merge conflicts

```
git add src/main/resources/conflicted_file.py
git commit
git push origin my_branch
```